# Nuke 'sp_askbrent' tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, retag-request

That stored procedure doesn't exist anymore and people seem to enjoy tagging both [random questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/276096/revisions) and anything related to sp_blitz with it still.

There are only [8 questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp-askbrent) using it (aside from the 3 I de-tagged in the past week or so) so there isn't much to lose by removing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [First Response Kit is missing sp_AskBrent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143129/first-response-kit-is-missing-sp-askbrent), this procedure was renamed to [`sp_BlitzFirst`](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/).

I removed [sp-askbrent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp-askbrent) from a few questions that needed editing anyway, then made [sp-askbrent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp-askbrent) a **synonym** of [sp-blitzfirst](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp-blitzfirst).

There might be some value in keeping the old name around for a while, so I didn't **merge** the tags. We might do that in the future.